# consulta sql en php solo me muestra el primer resultado

Tags: php, postgresql, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta ``sql`en`php`utilizando`postrgesql` como gestor, y la consulta sólo me muestra el primer resultado que encuentra, ya comprobé en la base de datos y debería mostrarme 13 resultados en el arreglo, mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
$query = "SELECT num_documento FROM letra_cambio where fecha_venc <= date '".$fecha_actual."'";
$resultado = pg_query($con, $query);
$res = pg_fetch_row($resultado);

echo json_encode($res);
```

así debería mostrarme todos los resultados posibles, por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias

Comment: Intenta con `pg_fetch_all`

Comment: resolví, muchas gracias

Comment: Ojo `pg_fetch_all` debe usarse solamente si esperas pocos datos. El código con  `pg_fetch_row` no funcionaba porque debes leer los datos dentro de un bucle. Lo que el manejador devuelve es un puntero a los datos, luegos debes moverlo para irlos sacando fila por fila. Esto es así precisamente para evitar problemas de rendimiento o memoria en resultados muy grandes. Es preciso que conozcas eso para evitar posibles bloqueos en tablas o resultados con muchos datos.

Comment: Por ejemplo, así debería funcionar: `$res array(); while( $row=pg_fetch_row($resultado) ){ $res[]=$row;; } echo json_encode($res);` Puede que en vez de `pg_fetch_row` convenga usar otro método, como `pg_fetch_assoc`, todo depende del resultado final que quieras.

Comment: @alanfcm `pg_fetch_all` puede ser problemático en algunos escenarios, por lo que no se debería recomendar sin advertirlo (ver nota en la respuesta a esta pregunta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Es importante que comprendas **por qué te mostraba sólo una línea** usando el código así:

```
$res = pg_fetch_row($resultado);
echo json_encode($res);
```

Cuando consultas a la base de datos, lo que recibes es un recurso o puntero hacia los datos. En este caso ese recurso se encuentra en la variable `$resultado`.

Para leer esos datos, existen varios métodos. Hay un método que es `pg_fetch_all` que mete todo el conjunto de resultados de golpe en una variable. Pero OJO, **este método no es recomendable cuando esperas muchos datos, porque podrías tener problemas de memoria o de rendimiento**<sup>1</sup>.

Por eso, generalmente los datos se leen fila por fila, moviendo el puntero dentro de un bucle. Si observas [los ejemplos del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-fetch-row.php), es así como se implementa al código.

En tu caso, sería algo así:

```
$resultado = pg_query($con, $query);
$res = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($resultado) ){
    $res[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

En este caso, se fue moviendo el recurso dentro del bucle `while` y metiendo a cada paso cada fila dentro del array representado por `$res`.

En el código de tu pregunta **el puntero no se seguía moviendo**, porque no se usaba un bucle, se aplicaba `pg_fetch_row` una sola vez al puntero de datos, y por eso sólo lograba sacarse de él la primera fila de resultados.

---

### Aparte de todo: un dato interesante

Algo interesante que puedes probar independiente de cualquier código es esto:

```
print_r(pg_fetch_row($resultado));
print_r(pg_fetch_row($resultado));
```

Verás que te saca las dos primeras filas de datos. ¿Por qué en el segundo `print_r` no saca también la primera fila? Porque en el primero el puntero se movió a la segunda.

Si de nuevo ejecutas:

```
print_r(pg_fetch_row($resultado));
```

Verás las tercera fila de resultados... Esto es ilustrativo para entender como funcionan los recursos que devuelven las consultas a la base de datos.

Espero sea de utilidad.

---

#### Notas:

1. Esto es lo que dice el Manual de PHP sobre [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php), aunque no se encuentra en la documentación relativa a postgresql, es válido también para este caso:

   > Usar este método para obtener conjuntos de resultados grandes **dará
   >   como resultado una fuerte demanda del sistema y, posiblemente, de los
   >   recursos de red**. En lugar de recuperar todos los datos y
   >   manipularlos en PHP, considérese usar el servidor de bases de datos
   >   para manipular los conjuntos de resultados. Por ejemplo, se pueden
   >   usar las cláusulas `WHERE` y `ORDER BY` en sentencias SQL para
   >   restringir el resultado antes de recuperarlos y procesarlos con PHP.

Comment: muy buena tu respuesta, una duda, exactamente a q le llaman grandes conjuntos de resultados? o sea de q cantidad de resultados estamos hablando

Comment: Esa es un pregunta difícil de responder @YasmanyAlonsoCabrera porque depende de varios factores, entre ellos, cuántas columnas trae la consulta, de qué tipo son, qué cantidad de memoria tienes permitida para PHP. Imaginemos una consulta a una tabla que trae capítulos de un libro, y te traes varios capítulos de unos cuantos megas o gigas de información y los metes todos de golpe usando `fetchAll`... es muy probable que el script se bloquee. Otro factor que juega en todo esto es la cantidad de usuarios: imaginemos varios miles de usuarios consultando esa misma info al mismo tiempo.

Comment: ya, entiendo, muchas gracias por todo